# ShinyApps: "shinythemes" package not loading when deployed on Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, package, shiny

I am trying to deploy an R Shiny app online. The app runs perfectly when deployed locally. It is basically just a dashboard of charts.

However when I deploy it on shinyapps.io, the app only displays the following error:

`"ERROR: there is no package called ‘shinythemes’".`

I'm guessing this means that somehow the online version of the app isn't able to load the `shinythemes` package, but I've search everywhere but I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem, or a solution.

Here is the code for the app's `ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  titlePanel("Bodhi Forest - Website Visitor Analysis"),
  selectInput("user_period","Use Data from the Last",c("7 days" = "7",
                                                       "30 days" = "30",
                                                       "60 days" = "60",
                                                       "90 days" = "90"),
              selected = "30"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Demographics",fluidPage(
      selectInput("Dem_Dim","Dimension",c("Age","Gender")),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,htmlOutput("Dem_Dim"),align="center")
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_Sessions",inline=TRUE),align="center"),
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_SessionLength",inline=TRUE),align="center")
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_Revenue",inline=TRUE),align="center"),
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_RevenuePerTransaction",inline=TRUE),align="center")
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_Users",inline=TRUE),align="center"),
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_NewUsers",inline=TRUE),align="center")
      ),
      br(),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,htmlOutput("Dem_Bounce",inline=TRUE),align="center")
      ),
      hr(),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,dataTableOutput("Dem_Table"))
      ),
      hr()
    )),
    tabPanel("Interests",fluidPage(
      selectInput("Int_Filter","",c(
        "Top 5",
        "Bottom 5"
      )),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_Sessions"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_SessionLength"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_Revenue"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_RevenuePerTransaction"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_Users"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_NewUsers"))),
        column(6,wellPanel(plotOutput("Int_Bounce")))
      ),
      hr(),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,dataTableOutput("Int_Table"))
      ),
      hr()
    ))
  )
))
```

The `server.R` code has no call to `shinythemes` so I'm guessing the error lies in `ui.R` but I can't figure out what needs to be done since I've seen other apps simply call `library(shinythemes)` and they work.

I have re-updated `shiny`,`shinyapps` and `shinythemes`, but to no avail.

Will really appreciate any help on this! Been trying to deploy this app for hours but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I had this problem a couple of times, and always in RStudio projects with a DESCRIPTION file that did not contain the offending package in the Imports section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325306/1873521

Comment: I have the same issue and still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

This is weird...but I figured out the weirdest solution to this. And somehow it has NOTHING to do with the `shinythemes` package! WHAT?!

So basically, in my `server.R` code, I included the `DT` and `rsconnect` packages. In the ui.R code, I used the `hr()` and `dataTableOutput()` functions. Now...the things is that these functions are contained within more than one package that has been loaded:

1. `hr()` is in both shiny and rsconnect.
2. `dataTableOutput()` is in both shiny and DT.

I simply added the namespace `shiny::` before these functions in ui.R as such:

1. `shiny::hr()`
2. `shiny::dataTableOutput()`

And when I tried deploying them on shinyapps again...WALA! The app works perfectly!

I'm just amused by the fact that I practically wasted a full day trying to figure this out, and amused by how the solution had nothing to do with the error message. Hope this saves truckloads of time for anyone who's facing the same problem.

Would still like to know why this is the case and why the error message was so misleading...Perhaps something for shiny developers to think about?

Comment: Im trying something similar but still not working... it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed super weird- I had a very similar problem, where I was using DT and had to go through and append things like `DT::dataTableOutput()` to every section calling the relevant functions.

I was able to fix this one with `shinythemes::shinytheme()` though of course I just uncovered more bugs after that, but hey progress.